# Failed to add a service

Tags: wcf

Getting error:

**Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.**

The service is working fine locally, but after deploying it in production i am getting the error for a single Service others are working fine.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

i have similar error in my service and after i find reason and i correct service.

i suggest for solve this problem, first comments all operation contracts (all your method) in interfaces and service types. then check your service, if service working properly and not problem, then you one by one uncomment operation contracts and equivalent service type until you find which op contract has potential of error.

good luck

Comment: this doesnt sound like a good answer to me. Normally the error  reported by Om. is due to some configuration problem (web.config). Normally a MEX endpoint is missing.

Comment: i have already this problem with my services and above approach was very useful for me and other my collaborations.